# vars.put function not writing the desired value into the jmeter parameter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Below is the code which i have been trying to address the below UseCase in JMETER.Quick help is appreciated.

Usecase:
A particular text like "History" in a page response needs to be validated and the if the text counts is more than 50 a random selection of the options within the page needs to be made.And if the text counts is less than 50 1st option needs to be selected.

I am new to Jmeter and trying to solve this usingJSR223 POST processor but somehow stuck at vars.put function where i am unable to see the desired number being populated within the V paramter.

Using a boundary extractor where match no  1 should suffice the 1st selection and 0 should suffice the random selection.

```
def TotalInstanceAvailable = vars.get("sCount_matchNr").toInteger()
log.info("Total Instance Available = ${TotalInstanceAvailable}");
def boundary_analyzer =50;
def DesiredNumber,V

if (TotalInstanceAvailable < boundary_analyzer)
{
    log.info("I am inside the loop")
     DesiredNumber = 0;
    log.info("DesiredNumber= ${DesiredNumber}");
    vars.put("V", DesiredNumber)
    log.info("v= ${V}");
}
else{
    DesiredNumber=1;
    log.info("DesiredNumber=${DesiredNumber}");
      vars.put("V", "DesiredNumber")
    log.info("v= ${V}");
}

def sCount = vars.get("sCount")
log.info("Text matching number is ${sCount_matchNr}")
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot store an integer in JMeter Variables using [vars.put()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#put-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) function, you either need to cast it to String first, to wit change this line:

   ```
   vars.put("V", DesiredNumber)
   ```

   to this one

   ```
   vars.put("V", DesiredNumber as String)
   ```

   alternatively you can use [vars.putObject()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#putObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) function which can store literally everything however you will be able to use the value only in JSR223 Elements by calling [vars.getObject()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#getObject-java.lang.String-)
2. Whenever you face a problem with your JMeter script get used to look at *jmeter.log* file or toggle [Log Viewer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) window - in absolute majority of cases you will find the root cause of your problem in the log file:

   [image: JMeter Log Viewer]